# Impedir o delete de um objeto pai caso o mesmo possua objetos filhos em JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-jpa

Existe alguma forma definida pelo JPA que impeça o exclusão de um objeto pai, caso este tenha algum objeto filho atrelado? Por exemplo:

Tenho a classe (Entity) Departamento, nela possuo o seguinte campo:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "departamento" )
public List<Usuario> getEmpregados() {
    return empregados;
}
```

O campo empregados é uma lista de empregados vinculados a este Departamento.

Preciso que ao solicitar a exclusão de um departamento, esta ação não ocorra caso tenha algum empregado vinculado a ela.

Analisando o JPA Cascade Type, não encontrei nenhuma opção que faça este bloqueio, a solução que vejo é fazer a validação manualmente antes de executar o comando delete do JPARepository referente ao Departamento.

Existe alguma forma da JPA fazer valer a integridade do banco e impedir que um objeto pai seja excluído por possuir filhos atrelados, algo tipo uma anotação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferi para o banco a responsabilidade de gerenciar a integridade referencial. Alterei no applicatoin.propertis o dialeto utilizado para a JPA conversar com o MySQL conforme abaixo:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect, assim as tabelas foram geradas encima da engine InnoDB criando assim os relacionamentos no banco.

Antes era a versão 5, as tabelas eram geradas utilizando a engine MyISAM.